# Trap output from powershell command in VB.net

Tags: powershell, output, vb.net-2010

Hi I'm working on a little VB.net apps to manage my distribution list on my exchange 2010 server.  This code call a ps1 scripts with 2 arguments and its work. the only problem I have is I want to trap the output  of the PowerShell.Invoke().  after the execution PowerShellCommandResults is allways empty no records in the collection.
Maybe the problem come from trapping from ps1 file but I really don't know where to look at to resolve my problem

thx

```
Dim PowerShell As Management.Automation.PowerShell = PowerShell.Create()
Dim PowerShellCommand As New PSCommand()
Dim PowerShellCommandResults As Collection(Of PSObject)

PowerShellCommand.AddCommand("c:\scripts\connect.ps1")

PowerShellCommand.AddCommand("c:\scripts\newld.ps1")
PowerShellCommand.AddArgument("test@cscapitale.qc.ca")
PowerShellCommand.AddArgument("Distribution liste test")

Try
            PowerShellCommandResults = PowerShell.Invoke()
            Dim sw As New StreamWriter("C:\" & Now.ToLongDateString & ".txt")
            For Each line In PowerShellCommandResults
                sw.WriteLine(line.ToString)
            Next

            sw.Dispose()
            PowerShell.Dispose()
 Catch ex As Exception

 End Try
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `Powershell.Invoke(IEnumerable, IList)` signature instead? I normally use C# so I may not have this completely right...

```
' Old and busted: PowerShellCommandResults = PowerShell.Invoke()
' New hotness:
PowerShell.Invoke(Nothing, PowerShellCommandResults)

' Everything below here is unchanged
Dim sw As New StreamWriter("C:\" & Now.ToLongDateString & ".txt")
For Each line In PowerShellCommandResults
    sw.WriteLine(line.ToString)
Next
```

Alternative Answer: Try using `PowerShellCommand.AddScript("C:\Scripts\Connect.ps1")`

Alternative Answer: Make sure the `connect.ps1` and `newld.ps1` scripts are outputting to the pipeline, not the Host.

```
# Bad: Explicitly writes to the host, and skips pipeline output
Write-Host "Some value"

# Good: A string, or variable on its own will be output on the pipeline
"Some Value"
$OtherVariable
```

Comment: thx the problem was my scripts they were not returning to pipeline!